# create new post using rest API and set featured Image from an external link

Tags: post-thumbnails, rest-api

I am new to Wordpress. I need to create a new post from the Rest API which has its featured image from an external link. I can successfully create a new post using the rest API plugin, how do I add featured images from an external link??

Comment: There's no built-in way to do that. What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: @swissspidy I have tried to create a meta field with my post parameters. I was hoping wordpress will automatically link the meta field to the featured_image value. I have added the meta tag to my request this way. "meta":{"featured_image_thumbnail":"http:\/\/www.autosportfoto.sk\/images\/art\/13348-breen-corse-black-2017-888-896x504-1.jpg","featured_image_full":"http:\/\/www.autosportfoto.sk\/images\/art\/big\/13348-breen-corse-black-2017-888-896x504-1.jpg"}. Please help